# Trying to write a list of the named ranges in my Google Sheet to a separate sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, named-ranges

I'm new to coding. I have a Google Sheet that includes 314 named range variables. I am trying to print a verticle list of all of the named ranges to a separate sheet in my workbook. The error I get is confusing. It reads

> Exception: The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 1 but the range has 314. (line 47, file "Code")

Here's my code. I am not sure what I'm missing?

```
function myFunction() {

//Declaring the Active Sheet
var mySheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

//Declaring Array 
var myArray = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();

//Clearing a range on the Google Sheet
mySheet.getRange('Named Ranges!A1:A314').clearContent();

//Printing Array to Google Sheet
mySheet.getRange('Named Ranges!A1:A314').setValues([myArray]);  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

### The method `getNamedRanges()` returns you the range objects rather than their names and `setValues` only works if the dimensions of the values correspond to the dimension of the range

- To retrieve the name ranges you need to iterate through all range objects and retrieve the name of each single range with [`getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range#getname)
- `[myArray]` will have the content `[[range1, range2, ...]]` which will be interpreted as an nested array will multiple columns and only one row
- To create an array with multiple columns and only one row you can do the following:

```
  var myRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
  Logger.log(myRanges);
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i< myRanges.length; i++){
    myArray[i] = [];
    myArray[i].push(myRanges[i].getName());
  }
```

- Given that your sheet `mySheet` is always the active sheet, you can specify a different sheet name within `getRange()`. Instead specify either

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('Named Ranges!A1:A314')
```

or even better dynamically:

```
var myRangeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Named Ranges');
myRangeSheet.getRange(1,1, myArray.length, 1)
```

- As the number of rows and columns in the data has to match the number of rows in the range, the latter approach the latter allows you to estimate the row number corresponding to the number of list entries dynamically, no matter what the number of the named ranges.
- It is not necessary to `clearContent()` before overwriting eventual data with `setValues`

**Sample modification of you code:**

```
function myFunction() {
  var myRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getNamedRanges();
  var myArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i< myRanges.length; i++){
    myArray[i] = [];
    myArray[i].push(myRanges[i].getName());
  }
  var myRangeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Named Ranges');
  myRangeSheet.getRange(1,1, myArray.length, 1).setValues(myArray);    
}
```